# How to show array data form controller in blade file (html table)? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Since I am completely new in Laravel, I have a problem pretty complicated for me.

I have controller file **ApiHandlerController** like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiHandlerController extends Controller
{
//
public function index()
{
    $client = new Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', '/todos');

    //get status code using $response->getStatusCode();

    $body = $response->getBody();
    $arr_body = json_decode($body);
    return view('myview', $arr_body);
}
}
?>
```

**myview.blade.php** as a view file:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Todo</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico">
        <meta name="description" content="HTML, PHP, JSON, REST API">
        <style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <table style="width:100%"; class="data-table">
        <tr>
            <th>User ID:</th>
            <th>ID:</th>
            <th>Title:</th>
            <th>Completed</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($arr_body as $value)  {    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value -> userId ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $value -> id ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $value -> title ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $value -> completed ?> </td>
            </tr>
        <?php  } ?>
   </table>
```

And **web.php** file with route:

```
Route::get('myview', function () {
    return view('myview');
});
```

My question is:

How to show result of todos from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com in this blade (view) file?
Currently, it's not possible, and every time I try this is an error:

> ErrorException
> Undefined variable: arr_body (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\TodoList\resources\views\myview.blade.php)
> Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Your route doesn't use the Controller (which doesn't look like a "valid" Laravel controller btw), it only returns a view.

Comment: @brombeer okay, what can be solution when we talk about route, in the first place?

Comment: [The Default Route Files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files) has examples on how to use a controller in routes, basically something like `Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);`. _Or_, you can use your controller code inside your `function()` in the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show array type data in blade...

First edit your controller code.

From:

```
return view('myview', $arr_body);
```

To:

```
return view('myview')->with('arr_body', $arr_body);
```

Below is core php syntex.

```
<td><?php echo $value['userId'] ?> </td>
```

Laravel syntex

```
<td>{{$value['userId']}}</td>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Won't solve the error though as there is no data

Comment: check your $data variable, it doent have data. dd it in controller.

Comment: @RajenTrivedi I just edited my question, still I have an error:  Undefined variable: arr_body